# Disable production datasource autoconfiguration in a Spring DataJpaTest

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, integration-testing, datasource

In my application.yml, I have the following configuration (to be able to customize variable on different environment with docker/docker-compose) :

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL}
    username: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME}
    password: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD}
```

The trouble is that Spring tries to autoconfigure this datasource while I am in @DataJpaTest, so with an embedded H2 database, and obviously it does not like placeholders....

I tried to exclude some autoconfiguration :

```
@DataJpaTest(excludeAutoConfiguration = 
               {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, 
                DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class, 
                HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
```

But then, nothing works, entityManagerFactory is missing, ...

I could probably use profiles but if possible I preferred another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try defining your own Datasource bean?

```
@Import(JpaTestConfiguration.class)
@DataJpaTest
```

---

```
@Configuration
public class JpaTestConfiguration{
//...
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1");
        dataSource.setUsername("sa");
        dataSource.setPassword("");
        return dataSource;
    }
//...
}
```